# .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rClr'

Tags: r, rclr

I am trying to build a package which has the namespace files as follows:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")

importFrom(rClr, clrLoadAssembly)
```

`rClr` is installed in my system.
I build my package using `devtools::build` and it successfully builds.

When I install the package using the following command `install.packages("C:/Package/Utils_0.1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'Utils' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rClr', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: 'msvcr120.dll' was not found on this Windows system.
You are probably missing the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013.
Check instructions at https://r2clr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installing%20R%20packages&referringTitle=Documentation
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/S.Bista/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/Utils'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/S.Bista/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/Utils'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/Users/S~1.BIS/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\S.Bista\Documents\R\R-3.3.2\library" "C:/Package/Utils_0.1.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Package/Utils_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Loading fails for `i386` but I have `x64` system.

Comment: Are you by any chance missing the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013? :)

Comment: @TimGoodman I have Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013. I have the `rClr` package installed in my system. While installing the package I did not get any error. When I try to import the package to create my a new package it gives me the error.

Comment: And are you able to locate the DLL it's complaining about? ('msvcr120.dll')  What folder is it in?  Also, if you run the following, does it succeed?  
`library(rClr)`  
`library(testthat)`  
`test_package('rClr')`

Comment: Yes I am able to locate the dll. Its in `C:/Windows/System32/msvcr120.dll`. Running the ` test_package('rClr')` fails. It gives the following error: `1. Failure: Date and Time objects are marshalled correctly (@test-datetime.r#196)` and `2. Failure: Date and Time objects are marshalled correctly (@test-datetime.r#198)`

Comment: Got it work using `install.packages("C:/pUtils_0.1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", INSTALL_opts = c("--no-multiarch"))`